# How do present information in a pricing table to make it less cluttered and overwhelming?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-expectation, tables, pricing

I'm working on a Pricing table that not only has a lot of plan options involved, but also a lot of features under each plan. The higher the plan, the more features you get.

To make it less overwhelming and cluttered, I thought that hiding full descriptions for each feature would be one way to go about it. The problem with this though is some of the features are not easily understandable at a glance, but making them understandable results in long sentences too.

Here's a quick illustration. Please note that there could be about 5-6 plans, and the higher-tier plans could have around 15 features.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The 'more info' CTA is redundant. You could provide something like a table. But this will only work if the features are the same within all plans. Something like this...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical **pricing plan** and there are many examples on the internet from where to get ideas.

Typing [pricing plan design](https://www.google.com/search?q=pricing%20plan%20design&rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKvfzBic3jAhUPlhQKHUhECJQQ_AUIESgB&biw=1685&bih=1173#imgrc=_) in Google and selecting images gives many options.

As an example (not spam), the [Publitas](https://www.publitas.com/pricing/) pricing plan has many features with a pop up dialog on each.

Comment: I loved how Publitas showed the "We are hiring" link beside the logo on the top left, so it appears whenever it's available. Nice idea to notice :) .. Regarding the pricing plan is also nice but I have a concern about the colors but overall is good

Answer (score 0):

The most important features for users have to be on top decreasing in direct proportion to their value.

if you have a lot of content, it is worth condensing it.
However accordance with the **Hick's & Miller's Law** there shouldn't be more than 7 (+/- 2) features.(The others features from 15 can be hide into "show/hide more" tertiary button.

Of course in your wireframes CTA is missing. You also can highlight the most using plan.

**To hide description You can also use tooltip:**

[image]